# Symfony2 Remove collection duplicates from the form in the controller

Tags: php, forms, symfony, duplicates

I have a form containing a collection (allowing add and remove entities) and a validation constraint to check if there are duplicates user's selections.

In case of there is of duplicates, the user is redirected in the new / edit form with an error message. 
**In this case, I am looking for a way to remove the duplicates fields from the form before rendering the view?**

I am able to remove the duplicates from the list in my entity, but not from the form fields.

```
public function createAction(Request $request)
{
    ...

    $form = $this->createCreateForm($entity);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {

        ...

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('ispc_show', array('id' => $entity->getId())));
    }

    // Remove the duplicates from the list in the entity
    $entity->removeDuplicate();
    // And apply to the form
    $form->remove....

    return $this->render('CompanyDocumentBundle:ISPC:new.html.twig', array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'form'   => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

**Update**

I don't want to remove the duplicates before validation because the error message is important to report to the user. Also, the duplicates are part of the "$request" object, and the form fields are filled with this object, not with the entity.

Comment: 1: You're filling the form with data (entities) before removing duplicates. 2: You really shouldn't be using the entity manager in your controller. The controller should leave that bit  up to a service of sorts, that's where the logic resides, not in an action

Comment: Try to call the createCreateFrom method after you remove the duplicate on it

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Thanks for your comment. 1: I don't want to remove the duplicates before validation because this message is important to report to the user. Also, the duplicates are part of the "$request" object, and the form fields are filled with this object, not the entity 2: I am using the official Symfony2 generator to create my CRUD, http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioGeneratorBundle/commands/generate_controller.html. So I am a bit confused about the best practices to use

Comment: @Matteo The createCreateFrom method petmits to create a "void" form fields, then the $form->handleRequest($request) petmits to fill the form with the requests parameters. Therefore, call createCreateFrom after removing the entity duplicates will not work because duplicates are part of the request object.

Comment: Perhaps using a FormEvent (POST_SUBMIT) to handle duplicates might be what you're looking for. It's not how you generate the bundle skeleton that matters, it's sticking to whole idea of MVC: Controllers receive the request data, pour that into objects, pass it on to the Model layer  (services, DB connection + data models), which in turn responds back to the controller, who than prepares the view with the data it obtained from the model layer. DB connections don't belong in the controller, which is just a go-between, really

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem You are right. I was just pointing the fact that the piece of code from my question comes from the generated action by the Symfony generator. That means Symfony recommends to use entity manager in the action in this case.

Comment: @sdespont: Symfony generates code that uses the entity manager in an action to allow a quick _functional_ action to be added. It does not mean that you should use that as a starting point to build larger applications. The more logic an action contains, the worse it is. Symfony _does not recommend using the em in the controller_, it just gives it to you so you can get something done, it's not because an auto-generated bit of code does something, that automatically means that the people who created said tool think that's the best way to do it

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem One more time, thanks for your comment and your advices. I admit that I have taken the generated code as solid bases because the bundle is edited by the Symfony team. Can you confirm that the best place to write DB logic (and operations like remove, flush, ...) is the entity repository?

Comment: This might be personal, but I tend to prefer using the services.yml resource to define a service that gets the entity manager (and any other dependencies it has) injected, and then in the controller simply write: `$service = $this->container->get('my_service_slug'); $entity = $service->removeDuplicatesFromEntity($entity);` How the service sets about doing what it does is irrelevant from the actions' point of view. I can use the container to get the service, pass it some data and request it to process it. That, to my eye, is the cleanest way

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem *thin controllers and fat models* OK, I get it. Last question, in which folder do you put the models classes? "AppBundle/Controller/Utils"? "AppBundle/models"?

Comment: @sdespont: I'm not talking about fat models. The way I use symfony, I have a `Model` namespace where I put my data containers (just some properties with getters and setters, nothing more). Then I have a main `Service` namespace (in the bundle root) which contains the logic. In this Service namespace, there often are various sub trees like `Service\Storage` and `Service\Http` for DB and API calls respectively). A `Utils`  NS is something I sometimes use for static helpers (encoding, XML parsers etc...). Tl;tr: models in `Model`, logic in `Service`, that's how I do things, but that's just me